# \label seems to need space when used with gb4e

Tags: cross-referencing, linguistics, gb4e

I try to keep examples typeset with `gb4e` on the same page. I extended gb4e by two shortcodes that wrap examples in a tabular environment. This worked until recently but now I get problems with `\label` in examples. `\label` seems to take space.

With a label, there is an additional newline:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gb4e}


\makeatletter
\def\eas{\ifnum\@xnumdepth=0\begin{exe}[(34)]\else\begin{xlist}[iv.]\fi\ex\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{.98\linewidth}@{}}}
\def\zs{\end{tabular}\ifnum\@xnumdepth=1\end{exe}\else\end{xlist}\fi}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\eas
\label{x}%
This is a very long sentence that goes on and on and on.
This is a very long sentence that goes on and on and on.
This is a very long sentence that goes on and on and on.
\zs

\eas
This is a very long sentence that goes on and on and on.
This is a very long sentence that goes on and on and on.
This is a very long sentence that goes on and on and on.
\zs

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try changing the definitions of `\eas` and `\zs` to `\def\eas{\ifnum\@xnumdepth=0\begin{exe}[(34)]\else\begin{xlist}[iv.]\fi\ex}
\def\zs{\ifnum\@xnumdepth=1\end{exe}\else\end{xlist}\fi}`

Comment: But this removes the tabular environment, doesn't it? This was added to keep things on the same page. It is the purpose of this special command.

Comment: Ah, I did wonder why the tabular.  Try then `\def\eas{\ifnum\@xnumdepth=0\begin{exe}[(34)]\else\begin{xlist}[iv.]\fi\ex\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{.98\linewidth}@{}}\leavevmode}`

Comment: Thanks! This works! Made my day.

Comment: Do you know why \label creates space? That seems to have changed in my installation. Is this dependend of the tex installation? I had texlive 2020 (mactex). Maybe I updated the core system but I did not update any packages. The out of the box texlive did not have this problem.

Comment: Sorry for not answering earlier: had some chores to do.  I added a (hopefully useful) explanation in the answer below.  I find it unlikely (but not impossible) that it worked before: the interaction is between `tabular` and `\label`, two commands in LaTeX that haven't changed in quite a while, so the behaviour should be the same.  I tested with TeX Live from 2015 to 2021 and the output looks the same.

Comment: Thanks! It worked for years. Maybe something in the exe environment changed. Even with the fix I need the % character since otherwise I have whitespace added by the \label command. I think this was not there earlier.

Comment: Hm... Indeed, the `\label` command should suppress the whitespace added at that point (also something that has been around for ages). There is something really weird with your installation.  What TeX distribution (TeX Live? MiKTeX?) and LaTeX version do you have?

Comment: This is texlive 2020 on a Mac (MacTeX comes with a fixed package including everything). I just reinstalled it completely from scratch. I have texlive 2021 installed in addition. Maybe this messed something up. No idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is boils down to

```latex
\parindent=0pt
(1)\vtop{\write0{x}This}

(2)\vtop{This}
```

which outputs:

> [image]

The `tabular` in your `\eas` command starts a `\vtop` (a `\vbox` that aligns at the top), and the `\label` does a `\write`.  However when the `\vtop` starts, TeX is in vertical mode, so the `\label` (`\write`) is added to the current vertical list (as if it were on a line of its own), then when your paragraph starts, TeX adds it below the `\write` in the vertical list, making it look as if it skipped a line.

The solution is to not use `\label` in vertical mode: you can either put it somewhere else in the text, or you can tell TeX to explicitly leave vertical mode right after the `\vtop` starts using `\leavevmode`: you are likely not going to need it in vertical mode at this point.  Thus, adding `\leavevmode` at the end of the definition of `\eas` solves the problem:

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\makeatletter
\def\eas{\ifnum\@xnumdepth=0\begin{exe}[(34)]\else\begin{xlist}[iv.]\fi
  \ex\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{.98\linewidth}@{}}%
  \leavevmode} %<-- added
\def\zs{\end{tabular}\ifnum\@xnumdepth=1\end{exe}\else\end{xlist}\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\eas
\label{x}%
This is a very long sentence that goes on and on and on.
This is a very long sentence that goes on and on and on.
This is a very long sentence that goes on and on and on.
\zs

\eas
This is a very long sentence that goes on and on and on.
This is a very long sentence that goes on and on and on.
This is a very long sentence that goes on and on and on.
\zs

\end{document}
```

Comment: I had to find some way to credit you for `{g +g}`, +1.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes No need for that, but thanks :)